# Margin can't possition button and textarea

Tags: css, button, textarea, css-position, margin

[image]Need to move Note button  right in line with text(by:Aleksa Kovacevic) 
I try margine-left but dont work idk why.
I need to textarea(result) move top but margine(margin-bottom: 600px;) dont work.
I dont know why my textarea is stiky with form.Every  answer will help me.

```js
function  Git(){
   window.open("https://github.com/thelexa");

}
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Cal");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function runLB(){
  document.case.display.value += "("
}
function runRB(){
  document.case.display.value += ")"
}
function run1(){
 document.case.display.value += "1"
};
function run2(){
 document.case.display.value += "2"
};
function run3(){
 document.case.display.value += "3"
};
function run4(){
 document.case.display.value += "4"
};
function run5(){
 document.case.display.value += "5"
};

function run6(){
    document.case.display.value += "6"
};
function run7(){
 document.case.display.value += "7"
};
function run8(){
 document.case.display.value += "8"
};
function run9(){
 document.case.display.value += "9"
};
function run0(){
 document.case.display.value += "0"
};
function runPlus(){
 document.case.display.value += "+"
};
function runMinus(){
 document.case.display.value += "-"
};
function runDivide(){
 document.case.display.value += "/"
};
function runMultiply(){
    document.case.display.value += "*"
};
function runComma(){
 document.case.display.value += "."
};
function runBack(){
 var val = document.case.display.value.slice(0, -1);
    document.case.display.value = val;
};
function runC(){
 document.case.display.value = ""
};
function runEquals() {
        if (document.case.display.value == "") {
         document.case.display.value = ""
        } else  {
 var equals = eval(document.case.display.value)
 document.case.display.value = equals;
}
}

function clickCounter() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (sessionStorage.clickcount) {
      sessionStorage.clickcount = Number(sessionStorage.clickcount)+1;
    } else {
      sessionStorage.clickcount = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + sessionStorage.clickcount + " time(s) in this session.";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage";
  }
}
```

```css
html {
background:
 linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
}
ul {
 list-style: none;
}
body {
 width: 500px;

}
#Git{
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6);
  left: 94.5%;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-size: 400%;

}
#His {
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 width: 200px;
 height: 60px;
 line-height: 60px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 24px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background:linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.9), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.9));
 background-size: 400%;
 border-radius: 30px;
 z-index: 1;
}
#His:hover
{
 animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animate
{
 0%
 {
  background-position: 0%;
 }
 100%
 {
  background-position: 500%;
 }
}
#His:before
{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: -5px;
 left: -5px;
 right: -5px;
 bottom: -5px;
 z-index: -1;
 background: linear-gradient(90deg, #03a9f4, #f441a5, #ffeb3b, #03a9f4);
 background-size: 400%;
 border-radius: 40px;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
#His:hover:before
{
 filter: blur(20px);
 opacity:1;
 animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}
{}

form {
 background:linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
 text-align: center;
 padding: 7px;
 align-content: center;
 border-radius: 10px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6);

}
#display {
 width: 98%;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: right;
 font-size: 3rem;
    margin: 7px;
 border: 5px solid rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.9);

}
.digit {
 font-size: 2rem;
 background-color:  #f8f8f8;
 height: 55px;
 width: 20%;
    border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
 display: inline-block;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px;
 color:#444;
 font-family: Roboto-Regular,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
 margin: 2px;
 opacity: 0.9;
}
.oper {
 font-size: 2rem;
 background-color: #d6d6d6;
 height: 55px;
 width: 20%;
 color: #444;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 2px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px;
 font-family: Roboto-Regular,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
 opacity: 0.9;
}
#equal {
 background-color:rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6) ;
 color: white;
 width: 41.5%;


}
textarea {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  resize: none;
  width: 520px;
  height: 400px;
  max-width: 405px;
  max-height: 400px;
  margin-left: 36px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: 3px solid rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.9);

}
#by {
 color: white;
 font-size: 27px;
 margin-right: 200px;
}
#result {
margin-left: 600px;
margin-bottom: 600px;
display:block
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculator Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<button type="button" id="Git" onclick="Git()"> GitHub</button>
<form name="case" >
  <input name="display" id="display" value="">
    <input type="button" class="oper" value="(" onclick="runLB()">
    <input type="button" class="oper" value=")" onclick="runRB()">
    <input type="button" id="back"  class="oper"  value="CE" onclick="runBack()">
   <input type="button" id="divide"  class="oper"  value="÷" onclick="runDivide()" >

    <input type="button" class="digit" value="1" onclick="run1()">
    <input type="button" class="digit" value="2" onclick="run2()">
    <input type="button" class="digit" value="3" onclick="run3()">
    <input type="button" id="multiply"  class="oper"  value="×" onclick="runMultiply()">

    <input type="button" class="digit" value="4" onclick="run4()">
    <input type="button" class="digit" value="5" onclick="run5()">
    <input type="button" class="digit" value="6" onclick="run6()">
    <input type="button" id="minus"  class="oper"  value="-" onclick="runMinus()" >

    <input type="button" class="digit" value="7" onclick="run7()">
    <input type="button" class="digit" value="8" onclick="run8()">
    <input type="button" class="digit" value="9" onclick="run9()">
    <input type="button" id="plus"  class="oper"  value="+"  onclick="runPlus()">

    <input type="button" class="digit" value="0" onclick="run0()">
    <input type="button" id="comma" class="digit" value="." onclick="runComma()">
    <input type="button" id="equal"  class="oper" value="=" onclick="runEquals()">

<div id="Cal">
<textarea   placeholder="Note"></textarea>
</div>
<p id="by">By: Aleksa Kovacevic</p>
<button type="button" id="His" onclick="myFunction()"> Note</button>
</form>

<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
<textarea  id="result" placeholder="Note"></textarea>
</body>
```

This is simple Cacluator.
Sorry about bad Englesh.

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, do you need this? https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/3/31/fce31183f609cc3f2d8e6f74cd4fc504-full.png

Comment: plz if you can explain the final result you want

Comment: To begin with, you are trying to position two block elements in the same line - p and button. You will need either floats or display: inline-block and a correction on the margin values to make it work. But with the second part of your question... Can you provide some more details on what you're trying to achieve with your textarea and why do you think it's sticky?

Comment: Sorry for small detail i add picuture what need to look like.I you will understend now

Comment: @TheLexa check my answer plz if something need to fix tell me

Comment: @godfather thanks :)

Comment: np glad that this helped you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dont use margins wrap the whole content with a div and display flex will align them and the text and button also the same thing

```js
function  Git(){
   window.open("https://github.com/thelexa");

}
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Cal");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function runLB(){
  document.case.display.value += "("
}
function runRB(){
  document.case.display.value += ")"
}
function run1(){
 document.case.display.value += "1"
};
function run2(){
 document.case.display.value += "2"
};
function run3(){
 document.case.display.value += "3"
};
function run4(){
 document.case.display.value += "4"
};
function run5(){
 document.case.display.value += "5"
};

function run6(){
    document.case.display.value += "6"
};
function run7(){
 document.case.display.value += "7"
};
function run8(){
 document.case.display.value += "8"
};
function run9(){
 document.case.display.value += "9"
};
function run0(){
 document.case.display.value += "0"
};
function runPlus(){
 document.case.display.value += "+"
};
function runMinus(){
 document.case.display.value += "-"
};
function runDivide(){
 document.case.display.value += "/"
};
function runMultiply(){
    document.case.display.value += "*"
};
function runComma(){
 document.case.display.value += "."
};
function runBack(){
 var val = document.case.display.value.slice(0, -1);
    document.case.display.value = val;
};
function runC(){
 document.case.display.value = ""
};
function runEquals() {
        if (document.case.display.value == "") {
         document.case.display.value = ""
        } else  {
 var equals = eval(document.case.display.value)
 document.case.display.value = equals;
}
}

function clickCounter() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (sessionStorage.clickcount) {
      sessionStorage.clickcount = Number(sessionStorage.clickcount)+1;
    } else {
      sessionStorage.clickcount = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + sessionStorage.clickcount + " time(s) in this session.";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage";
  }
}
```

```css
#wrapper{display:flex;}
#newpos{display:flex;}

html {
background:
 linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
}
ul {
 list-style: none;
}
body {
 width: 500px;

}
#Git{
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6);
  left: 94.5%;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-size: 400%;

}
#His {
 transform: translate(0,50%);
 width: 200px;
 height: 60px;
 line-height: 60px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 24px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background:linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.9), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.9));
 background-size: 400%;
 border-radius: 30px;
 z-index: 1;
}
#His:hover
{
 animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animate
{
 0%
 {
  background-position: 0%;
 }
 100%
 {
  background-position: 500%;
 }
}
#His:before
{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: -5px;
 left: -5px;
 right: -5px;
 bottom: -5px;
 z-index: -1;
 background: linear-gradient(90deg, #03a9f4, #f441a5, #ffeb3b, #03a9f4);
 background-size: 400%;
 border-radius: 40px;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
#His:hover:before
{
 filter: blur(20px);
 opacity:1;
 animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}
{}

form {
 background:linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
 text-align: center;
 padding: 7px;
 align-content: center;
 border-radius: 10px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6);

}
#display {
 width: 98%;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: right;
 font-size: 3rem;
    margin: 7px;
 border: 5px solid rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.9);

}
.digit {
 font-size: 2rem;
 background-color:  #f8f8f8;
 height: 55px;
 width: 20%;
    border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
 display: inline-block;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px;
 color:#444;
 font-family: Roboto-Regular,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
 margin: 2px;
 opacity: 0.9;
}
.oper {
 font-size: 2rem;
 background-color: #d6d6d6;
 height: 55px;
 width: 20%;
 color: #444;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 2px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px;
 font-family: Roboto-Regular,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
 opacity: 0.9;
}
#equal {
 background-color:rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6) ;
 color: white;
 width: 41.5%;


}
textarea {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  resize: none;
  width: 520px;
  height: 400px;
  max-width: 405px;
  max-height: 400px;

  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: 3px solid rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.9);

}
#by {
text-align:left;
 color: white;
 font-size: 27px;

}
#result {

display:block
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculator Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>


<button type="button" id="Git" onclick="Git()"> GitHub</button>
<div id="wrapper">
<form name="case" >
  <input name="display" id="display" value="">
    <input type="button" class="oper" value="(" onclick="runLB()">
    <input type="button" class="oper" value=")" onclick="runRB()">
    <input type="button" id="back"  class="oper"  value="CE" onclick="runBack()">
   <input type="button" id="divide"  class="oper"  value="÷" onclick="runDivide()" >

    <input type="button" class="digit" value="1" onclick="run1()">
    <input type="button" class="digit" value="2" onclick="run2()">
    <input type="button" class="digit" value="3" onclick="run3()">
    <input type="button" id="multiply"  class="oper"  value="×" onclick="runMultiply()">

    <input type="button" class="digit" value="4" onclick="run4()">
    <input type="button" class="digit" value="5" onclick="run5()">
    <input type="button" class="digit" value="6" onclick="run6()">
    <input type="button" id="minus"  class="oper"  value="-" onclick="runMinus()" >

    <input type="button" class="digit" value="7" onclick="run7()">
    <input type="button" class="digit" value="8" onclick="run8()">
    <input type="button" class="digit" value="9" onclick="run9()">
    <input type="button" id="plus"  class="oper"  value="+"  onclick="runPlus()">

    <input type="button" class="digit" value="0" onclick="run0()">
    <input type="button" id="comma" class="digit" value="." onclick="runComma()">
    <input type="button" id="equal"  class="oper" value="=" onclick="runEquals()">

<div id="Cal">
<textarea   placeholder="Note"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="newpos">
<p id="by">By: Aleksa Kovacevic</p>
<button type="button" id="His" onclick="myFunction()"> Note</button></div>
</form>
<div id="new">
<button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button>
<textarea  id="result" placeholder="Note"></textarea></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: if that what you want so plz tell me what you want to fix more

Answer (score 0):

Changes required in your exist code.

Refer this

```
<body>
<button type="button" id="Git" onclick="Git()"> GitHub</button>
<div class="form">
    <form name="case" >
      <input name="display" id="display" value="">
        <input type="button" class="oper" value="(" onclick="runLB()">
        <input type="button" class="oper" value=")" onclick="runRB()">
        <input type="button" id="back"  class="oper"    value="CE" onclick="runBack()">
       <input type="button" id="divide"     class="oper"    value="÷" onclick="runDivide()" >

        <input type="button" class="digit" value="1" onclick="run1()">
        <input type="button" class="digit" value="2" onclick="run2()">
        <input type="button" class="digit" value="3" onclick="run3()">
        <input type="button" id="multiply"  class="oper"    value="×" onclick="runMultiply()">

        <input type="button" class="digit" value="4" onclick="run4()">
        <input type="button" class="digit" value="5" onclick="run5()">
        <input type="button" class="digit" value="6" onclick="run6()">
        <input type="button" id="minus"     class="oper"    value="-" onclick="runMinus()" >

        <input type="button" class="digit" value="7" onclick="run7()">
        <input type="button" class="digit" value="8" onclick="run8()">
        <input type="button" class="digit" value="9" onclick="run9()">
        <input type="button" id="plus"  class="oper"    value="+"  onclick="runPlus()">

        <input type="button" class="digit" value="0" onclick="run0()">
        <input type="button" id="comma" class="digit" value="." onclick="runComma()">
        <input type="button" id="equal"     class="oper"    value="=" onclick="runEquals()">

    <div id="Cal">
    <textarea   placeholder="Note"></textarea>
    </div>
    <p id="by">By: Aleksa Kovacevic</p>
    <button type="button" id="His" onclick="myFunction()"> Note</button>
    </form>
    <p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
</div>
<textarea  id="result" placeholder="Note"></textarea>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html {
background:
    linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
body {
    width: 100%;

}
#Git{
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6);
  left: 94.5%;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-size: 400%;

}
#His {
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 width: 200px;
 height: 60px;
 line-height: 60px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 24px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background:linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.9), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.9));
 background-size: 400%;
 border-radius: 30px;
 z-index: 1;
}
#His:hover
{
 animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animate
{
 0%
 {
  background-position: 0%;
 }
 100%
 {
  background-position: 500%;
 }
}
#His:before
{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: -5px;
 left: -5px;
 right: -5px;
 bottom: -5px;
 z-index: -1;
 background: linear-gradient(90deg, #03a9f4, #f441a5, #ffeb3b, #03a9f4);
 background-size: 400%;
 border-radius: 40px;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
#His:hover:before
{
 filter: blur(20px);
 opacity:1;
 animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}﻿
{}

form {
    background:linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7px;
    align-content: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6);
}
.form {
    width:35%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#result {
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#display {
    width: 98%;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin: 7px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.9);

}
.digit {
    font-size: 2rem;
    background-color:   #f8f8f8;
    height: 55px;
    width: 20%;
    border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px;
    color:#444;
    font-family: Roboto-Regular,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    margin: 2px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.oper {
    font-size: 2rem;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    height: 55px;
    width: 20%;
    color: #444;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px;
    font-family: Roboto-Regular,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
#equal {
    background-color:rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6) ;
    color: white;
    width: 41.5%;


}
textarea {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  resize: none;
  width: 520px;
  height: 400px;
  max-width: 405px;
  max-height: 400px;
  margin-left: 36px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: 3px solid rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.9);

}
#by {
    color: white;
    font-size: 27px;
    margin-right: 200px;
}
```